# How to generate private LINQ to SQL classes?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to make the generated [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) classes be marked private instead of public, so that it is not visible outside the assembly.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the Visual Studio O/R designer or the [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) tool, unless I'm missing something.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm asking because I'm using LINQ to SQL internally as a data access layer in a business logic assembly.  I am exposing to clients a separate set of custom entity classes, and I don't want the LINQ to SQL classes to be exposed at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, in the Visual Studio Designer select the class and in properties you can change *Access* to *Internal*.

[alt text http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/970/l2svs2008access.png](http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/970/l2svs2008access.png)

The same principles apply for the *DataContext* itself (just click in the "white area" of the designer) and change under *Properties*.

Comment: Great, I missed that.  Also, it looks like I can do a CTRL-A to select all classes and then set the Access property on all of them at once (otherwise this solution would not have been practical due to number of classes).

Comment: This still exposes the generated data context class.  I'll wait a bit and see if anyone has an even better approach that makes everything private... then I'll accept the best answer.

Comment: Note! I added "Same principles apply for the DataContext itself (just click in the "white area" of the designer) and change under Properties"

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I do wish the there was some project option in VS that would just generate private classes by default, but this is good enough.