# How to make linq to sql classes internal or private?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437542/how-to-generate-private-linq-to-sql-classes) question/answer about setting linq to sql classes as internal, but one thing I found is that classes generated for stored procedure return types are set as public, and even though I set the access modifier for the stored procedure and the data contest class as internal, the generated class for the stored proc is still public.  How can I make it internal.  I'm doing this in a seperate data access layer assembly, so I don't want these classes exposed to applicaitons.

Answer (score 1):

Create a partial classes to call the stored procedures. I would generate the code as normal then paste them into a separate file and then delete the stored procedures from the design surface. You can then set the access modifiers as you wish. This is also a useful technique for dealing with stored procedures whereLINQ to SQL does not generate the classes as you would expect, such as those that use temporary tables.

internal partial class DataClasses2DataContextExtended : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {

```
    [Function(Name="dbo.SPDEMO")]
    internal ISingleResult<SPDEMOResult> SPDEMO()
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
        return ((ISingleResult<SPDEMOResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
}

internal partial class SPDEMOResult
{

    public SPDEMOResult()
    {
    }

    public System.Nullable<int> FilmID
    { get; set; }


    public string FilmName
    { get; set; }
}
```