# XML comment of C# DLL not showing in VB.Net project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I have a solution with some "historic" VB.Net projects in it (too big, no time to convert now) and the rest of the solution is C#. The XML comments of the C# DLL projects are not showing up in the VB.Net projects.

Is there a way to make it work other than creating a XML documentation file when building (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482609))?

I tried it on one DLL project and it works, but I can't use it for some DLLs. The classes autogenerated for Linq to SQL don't have XML comments and are throwing tons of warnings. Even if I disable treat all warnings as errors I can't stay with 280 warnings.

Comment: You will need to turn on the XML generated file if you want the comments to show up.

Comment: I can't have hundreds of warnings. If there is nothing else I'll do without until I get rid of these VB.Net projects. I'm quite sure it was working out of the box in VS 2010.

Comment: If you can, change the access on generated classes to Internal. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1437582/2226988).